# Installing npm on Centos 7

Tags: centos, node.js, npm

I can say I went through **all Google results regarding this**, but no one works. The GNU libc version is very old:
`ldd (GNU libc) 2.17`.

Trying version up to `nodesource 8.x` **all installations fails because of the old GNU libc**:

```
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-19.9.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:nodejs-19.9.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
```

What can I do? Would it help when I try to build node from the source with `gcc-c++`? Reading the requirements I doubt this will work because Centos 7 has also a very old gcc version which is not supported anymore, or am I wrong?

Any hints?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/894625/safely-upgrade-glibc-on-centos-7

Comment: @K-att- I don't really think this is the solution. The way how to fix it in the link you provided is for programs which fail to run due to wrong glibc version. In my case I **CANNOT** install a program because the system `glibc` is too old. Therefore I would have to provide `yum` the path to the  newer `glibc` and how to do it?

Comment: I think the safe way is to upgrade to OL8. 
Patched centos 7 => `file /usr/lib/libm.so.6
/usr/lib/libm.so.6: symbolic link to libm-2.17.so'`

Ol8 => `file /usr/lib64/libm.so.6
/usr/lib64/libm.so.6: symbolic link to libm-2.28.so`

Comment: @K-attila- This is a hosted server with Plesk. I don't think I can do it as the hoster doesn't provide OL8. I can install a new server with Ubuntu 22.04 and I think, I will invest in the holidays few days to install the new server and migrate the existing one. Centos 7 is anyway close to the EOL.

Comment: Yes, it is a good solution, too. You can hack the Centos, but why_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I got it work:***

1. cloning it from Github - V19.9.0
2. Installing C++ 11
3. Setting the proper `export` variables for `configure`
4. Compiling and installing it.
5. This are now the installed versions:

> ```
> root@server:/usr/local/src/node => npm version
> {
>
>   npm: '9.6.3',
>   node: '19.9.0',
>   acorn: '8.8.2',
>   ada: '1.0.4',
>   ares: '1.19.0',
>   brotli: '1.0.9',
>   cldr: '42.0',
>   icu: '72.1',
>   llhttp: '8.1.0',
>   modules: '111',
>   napi: '8',
>   nghttp2: '1.52.0',
>   nghttp3: '0.7.0',
>   ngtcp2: '0.8.1',
>   openssl: '3.0.8+quic',
>   simdutf: '3.2.3',
>   tz: '2023c',
>   undici: '5.21.0',
>   unicode: '15.0',
>   uv: '1.44.2',
>   uvwasi: '0.0.16',
>   v8: '10.8.168.25-node.16',
>   zlib: '1.2.13'
> }
>
> root@server:~ => cat /etc/centos-release
> CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
>
> root@server:~ => ldd --version
> ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
> Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
> Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
> ```